# How can I check if my compiled C++ packages are compatible with my current version of node?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

When I update my node version I find that I need to rebuild the packages that use compiled C++ binaries like bcrypt. I get an error like NODE_MODULE_VERSION mismatch. Other answers correctly state that to fix this I can run the command `npm rebuild --build-from-source`. I want to write a script to check if these libraries are in need of an update proactively rather than waiting for my build to fail. How can I check if my version of node is compatible with the current compiled binaries for these packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with node's binary interpreter. According to [this node version page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)

> NODE_MODULE_VERSION refers to the ABI (application binary interface) version number of Node.js, used to determine which versions of Node.js compiled C++ add-on binaries can be loaded in to without needing to be re-compiled. It used to be stored as hex value in earlier versions, but is now represented as an integer.

However it takes some digging to find that the current NODE_MODULE_VERSION can be printed like so:

```
node -p process.versions.modules
```

Compiled binaries include a config.gypi file which lists the NODE_MODULE_VERSION that the package was compiled against.

Thus in order to check if your binaries are compiled correctly you can run the following script:

```
VERSION_MISMATCH=$(grep -E "\"node_module_version\": " -r ./node_modules --include "config.gypi" | grep -v "$(node -p process.versions.modules)")
if [ ${#VERSION_MISMATCH} > 0 ]; then
   npm rebuild --build-from-source -q
fi
```

I would recommend listing out all the packages that you'd expect would need rebuilding in the rebuild statement, e.g.

```
npm rebuild bcrypt ... --build-from-source -q
```

so that you only rebuild your ABI packages. You also might be able to modify the script above to rebuild only the ABI packages that were found in the grep.